# Nodejs lags with timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason, whenever I do `console.log(new Date().getTime()` in Nodejs, it gives me a timestamp with about a ~5 second delay. I've verified that the time coming from the client is essentially nanosecond to nanosecond with real time, and so doing something like the below yields these results:

```
console.log(new Date().getTime()); // 1587659588926
console.log(new Date(timeFromClient).getTime()); // 1587659593670
```

Why is this happening? I am positive that `timeFromClient` is the correct time... so why is Nodejs delayed?

Comment: It's more likely your server, and not node.js, which is 5 seconds behind. Try comparing your server's reported time with that of the client if possible.

Comment: Is the client and the server on same machine ?

Comment: @Klaycon So, if this backend is deployed to something like AWS, I won't have this issue?

Comment: @rksh1997 Both are on the same machine, yes.

Comment: @MikeK If they are currently on the same machine the times should be the same, actually. How are you obtaining `timeFromClient`?